# Comparing ints in math game PHP

Tags: php, math, post, int, operators

I have a simple math game I've made where the user can answer the question and then it checks if the input answer is correct.

I want it to say correct when the answer is correct, and incorrect when it isn't. So far, I haven't seen the correct string show up, even when I know that the answer I put in is correct.

I believe it has something to do with my `$_POST`, but I'm not entirely sure. How can I fix this?

```
<html>
<head><title>Addition php</title></head>
<body>
<h1>MATH GAME WOOOO</h1>

    <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="guess"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="guess-butt"><br>
    </form>

<?php

    $operators = array("+", "-", "*", "/");
    $operator = $operators[rand(0,2)];
    $rand_int1 = rand(0, 10);
    $rand_int2 = rand(0, 10);

    echo("<a>What is " . $rand_int1 . ' ' . $operator . ' ' . $rand_int2 . "?</a><br>");
    echo('guess for last question: ' . $_POST['guess'] . '<br>');

if (isset($_POST['guess'])) {

    $guess = intval($_POST['guess']);

    if ($operator == "+") 
    {
        $temp = $rand_int1 + $rand_int2;
        echo('answer: ' . $temp . "<br>" . '');
        if ($guess == $temp) 
        {
            echo("<br>correct<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo('<br>incorrect<br>');
        }
    } 

    elseif ($operator == "-") 
    {
        $temp = $rand_int1 - $rand_int2;
        echo('answer: ' . $temp . "<br>" . '');
        if ($guess == $temp) 
        {
            echo("<br>correct<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo('<br>incorrect<br>');
        }
    } 

    elseif ($operator == "*") 
    {
        $temp = $rand_int1 * $rand_int2;
        echo('answer: ' . $temp . "<br>" . '');
        if ($guess == $temp) 
        {
            echo("<br>correct<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo('<br>incorrect<br>');
        }
    } 

    elseif ($operator == "/") 
    {
        $temp = $rand_int1 / $rand_int2;
        echo('answer: ' . $temp . "<br>" . '');
        if ($guess == $temp) {
            echo("<br>correct<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo('<br>incorrect<br>');
        }
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$operators[rand(0,2)];` will never select `/`. You should use `array_rand()` to select a random element from an array.

Comment: I'm able to see all the operators...

Comment: Your guess is from the previous page load, which uses different random values.

Comment: You're testing the answer for the last question against the calculation for the current question.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `$rand_int1` and `$rand_int2` are randomized each time the page reloads. So the if a users sees the message "What is 5 + 6?" and answers it, the page submits a POST request to itself and `$rand_int1` and 2 contain newly randomized numbers. So it's very hard to get the correct answer.

You can try to also submit the `$rand_int1` and 2 variables as hidden input fields:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="rand_int1" value="<?php echo $rand_int1; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="rand_int2" value="<?php echo $rand_int2; ?>">
```

And than do something like:

```
$answer = $_POST['rand_int1'] + $_POST['rand_int2'];

echo('answer: ' . $answer . "<br>" . '');
if ($guess == $answer) 
{
    echo("<br>correct<br>");
}
else
{
    echo('<br>incorrect<br>');
}
```